# Add class to clicked button if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to make hangaman game so if the user click the correct letter 'dont-draw' class will be added if he enter the wrong letter another class will added, but is seems this if condition never became false

```
else if(theClickedLetter !== wordGeuss){

    e.target.classList.add('draw');
   
}
```

here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let theClickedLetter = e.target.textContent;

  arrayGuess.forEach((wordGeuss, index) => {

    if (theClickedLetter === wordGeuss) {
      e.target.classList.add('dont-draw');

      let n = Array.from(lettersGess.children);
      n[index].textContent = theClickedLetter;
    } 
    else if (theClickedLetter !== wordGeuss) {
      e.target.classList.add('draw');
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: You should use `else` when the two conditions are exact opposites.

Comment: The condition will be true for some elements of `arrayGuess`, but false for other elements. So you'll add both classes to `e.target`.

Answer (score 0):

So first think you can do to test what's going on is that you add an else in the end and see where the logic is ending up at. Since you didn't provide a complete HTML, I couldn't do much on the testing end so I can only suggest you how to test and possible fixes. Here's your code with an else:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let theClickedLetter = e.target.textContent;

  arrayGuess.forEach((wordGeuss, index) => {

    if (theClickedLetter === wordGeuss) {
      e.target.classList.add('dont-draw');

      let n = Array.from(lettersGess.children);
      n[index].textContent = theClickedLetter;
    } 
    else if (theClickedLetter !== wordGeuss) {
      e.target.classList.add('draw');
    }
    else {
      console.log('ending up in else')
    }
  })
})
```

Then you can see what's going wrong. Possible issues and fixes are

- The way you get the text from the event (try using other methods like e.target.innerText)
- Try printing both of the variables before the `if else` block and see what's gone wrong (see if the values actually match and debug accordingly)
- Just use an else at the end to put the code `e.target.classList.add('draw');`, that might be a possible solution